# How to store a private key in a protected custom setting for use in Crypto class?

Tags: customsetting, crypto

The Salesforce crypto class documentation specifies that a private key should be stored as a protected custom setting.

"A PKCS8 formatted private key in base64 decoded form is required. This private key should not be hardcoded in the Apex script but should be stored in a protected custom setting or a encrypted fields in a custom table"

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class

How do I do this because it seems that custom setting field values are limited to 255 characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only decent option is to split the private key into separate parts (probably around 10) and save those into the fields. Then in your code, concatenate the parts into the complete key.

I personally prefer a custom object field because it can be encrypted. Custom settings are accessible by all users with view setup/config rights.